# Introductory text on Group Cohomology

Tags: group-cohomology, textbook-recommendation

What are good introductory textbooks available on Cohomology of Groups?

Comment: IMO, you can't go wrong with Ken Brown's book. But you should add more detail to your question, including your background and motivation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the undergraduate level, some elements of group cohomology is explained in John Moody's book "Groups for Undergraduates" [http://www.amazon.com/Groups-Undergraduates-John-Atwell-Moody/dp/9810221053](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/9810221053)  At more advanced (but still undergraduate) level, see Maxim Stykow's Honours B.Sc. thesis "Introduction to
Group Cohomology" http://www.math.ubc.ca/~maxim/stykow_group_cohomology.pdf

At the graduate level, a good choice seems to be the above mentioned Ken Brown's book "Cohomology of Groups" [http://www.amazon.com/Cohomology-Groups-Graduate-Texts-Mathematics/dp/0387906886](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387906886)

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you are interested in *number theory*, http://www.mathi.uni-heidelberg.de/~schmidt/NSW2e/index-de.html (Jürgen Neukirch, Alexander Schmidt, Kay Wingberg:
Cohomology of Number Fields, second edition) and http://www.mathi.uni-heidelberg.de/~schmidt/Neukirch-en/index-de.html (Jürgen Neukirch: Class Field Theory-The Bonn Lectures). [These are textbooks covering (profinite) group cohomology with number theoretic applications in mind.]

Comment: I cannot see how this answer addresses the question...

Comment: Well, these are textbooks covering group cohomology?

Comment: Then I apologize for my hasty comment and downvote. I am afraid I cannot take it back now without editing the answer... Can you just mention briefly in your answer how these books address the question? Thanks, and I apologize once again for the impulsive downvote.